# HttpClient Get encoding characters on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encoding, titanium, httpclient

I want get html files and parse this page. But html return with encoding characters and I cant   solved this issue.

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
         // function called when the response data is available
         onload : function(e) {
            var data = this;
            callback(data);
         },
         onerror : function(e) {
            error();
         },
         timeout : 10000  // in milliseconds,
     });


     client.open("GET",_link);
     client.send();


Ka&shy;dın&shy;la&shy;rın or&shy;tak // A sample output &shy; &amp etc.
```

How can I solved this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function, `html_entity_decode` taken from this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/decode-html). For your string:

```
html_entity_decode("Ka&shy;dın&shy;la&shy;rın or&shy;tak");
"Ka­dın­la­rın or­tak"
```

Here is the actual function, it creates an ehaustive map of all the codes, then replaces them :

```
function html_entity_decode(string, quote_style) {
  var hash_map = {},
      symbol = '',
      tmp_str = '',
      entity = '';
  tmp_str = string.toString();

  if (false === (hash_map = get_html_translation_table('HTML_ENTITIES', quote_style))) {
    return false;
  }

  // fix &amp; problem
  // http://phpjs.org/functions/get_html_translation_table:416#comment_97660
  delete(hash_map['&']);
  hash_map['&'] = '&amp;';

  for (symbol in hash_map) {
    entity = hash_map[symbol];
    tmp_str = tmp_str.split(entity).join(symbol);
  }
  tmp_str = tmp_str.split('&#039;').join("'");

  return tmp_str;
}

function get_html_translation_table(table, quote_style) {
  var entities = {},
      hash_map = {},
      decimal;
  var constMappingTable = {},
      constMappingQuoteStyle = {};
  var useTable = {},
      useQuoteStyle = {};

  // Translate arguments
  constMappingTable[0] = 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS';
  constMappingTable[1] = 'HTML_ENTITIES';
  constMappingQuoteStyle[0] = 'ENT_NOQUOTES';
  constMappingQuoteStyle[2] = 'ENT_COMPAT';
  constMappingQuoteStyle[3] = 'ENT_QUOTES';

  useTable = !isNaN(table) ? constMappingTable[table] : table ? table.toUpperCase() : 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS';
  useQuoteStyle = !isNaN(quote_style) ? constMappingQuoteStyle[quote_style] : quote_style ? quote_style.toUpperCase() : 'ENT_COMPAT';

  if (useTable !== 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS' && useTable !== 'HTML_ENTITIES') {
    throw new Error("Table: " + useTable + ' not supported');
    // return false;
  }

  entities['38'] = '&amp;';
  if (useTable === 'HTML_ENTITIES') {
    entities['160'] = '&nbsp;';
    entities['161'] = '&iexcl;';
    entities['162'] = '&cent;';
    entities['163'] = '&pound;';
    entities['164'] = '&curren;';
    entities['165'] = '&yen;';
    entities['166'] = '&brvbar;';
    entities['167'] = '&sect;';
    entities['168'] = '&uml;';
    entities['169'] = '&copy;';
    entities['170'] = '&ordf;';
    entities['171'] = '&laquo;';
    entities['172'] = '&not;';
    entities['173'] = '&shy;';
    entities['174'] = '&reg;';
    entities['175'] = '&macr;';
    entities['176'] = '&deg;';
    entities['177'] = '&plusmn;';
    entities['178'] = '&sup2;';
    entities['179'] = '&sup3;';
    entities['180'] = '&acute;';
    entities['181'] = '&micro;';
    entities['182'] = '&para;';
    entities['183'] = '&middot;';
    entities['184'] = '&cedil;';
    entities['185'] = '&sup1;';
    entities['186'] = '&ordm;';
    entities['187'] = '&raquo;';
    entities['188'] = '&frac14;';
    entities['189'] = '&frac12;';
    entities['190'] = '&frac34;';
    entities['191'] = '&iquest;';
    entities['192'] = '&Agrave;';
    entities['193'] = '&Aacute;';
    entities['194'] = '&Acirc;';
    entities['195'] = '&Atilde;';
    entities['196'] = '&Auml;';
    entities['197'] = '&Aring;';
    entities['198'] = '&AElig;';
    entities['199'] = '&Ccedil;';
    entities['200'] = '&Egrave;';
    entities['201'] = '&Eacute;';
    entities['202'] = '&Ecirc;';
    entities['203'] = '&Euml;';
    entities['204'] = '&Igrave;';
    entities['205'] = '&Iacute;';
    entities['206'] = '&Icirc;';
    entities['207'] = '&Iuml;';
    entities['208'] = '&ETH;';
    entities['209'] = '&Ntilde;';
    entities['210'] = '&Ograve;';
    entities['211'] = '&Oacute;';
    entities['212'] = '&Ocirc;';
    entities['213'] = '&Otilde;';
    entities['214'] = '&Ouml;';
    entities['215'] = '&times;';
    entities['216'] = '&Oslash;';
    entities['217'] = '&Ugrave;';
    entities['218'] = '&Uacute;';
    entities['219'] = '&Ucirc;';
    entities['220'] = '&Uuml;';
    entities['221'] = '&Yacute;';
    entities['222'] = '&THORN;';
    entities['223'] = '&szlig;';
    entities['224'] = '&agrave;';
    entities['225'] = '&aacute;';
    entities['226'] = '&acirc;';
    entities['227'] = '&atilde;';
    entities['228'] = '&auml;';
    entities['229'] = '&aring;';
    entities['230'] = '&aelig;';
    entities['231'] = '&ccedil;';
    entities['232'] = '&egrave;';
    entities['233'] = '&eacute;';
    entities['234'] = '&ecirc;';
    entities['235'] = '&euml;';
    entities['236'] = '&igrave;';
    entities['237'] = '&iacute;';
    entities['238'] = '&icirc;';
    entities['239'] = '&iuml;';
    entities['240'] = '&eth;';
    entities['241'] = '&ntilde;';
    entities['242'] = '&ograve;';
    entities['243'] = '&oacute;';
    entities['244'] = '&ocirc;';
    entities['245'] = '&otilde;';
    entities['246'] = '&ouml;';
    entities['247'] = '&divide;';
    entities['248'] = '&oslash;';
    entities['249'] = '&ugrave;';
    entities['250'] = '&uacute;';
    entities['251'] = '&ucirc;';
    entities['252'] = '&uuml;';
    entities['253'] = '&yacute;';
    entities['254'] = '&thorn;';
    entities['255'] = '&yuml;';
  }

  if (useQuoteStyle !== 'ENT_NOQUOTES') {
    entities['34'] = '&quot;';
  }
  if (useQuoteStyle === 'ENT_QUOTES') {
    entities['39'] = '&#39;';
  }
  entities['60'] = '&lt;';
  entities['62'] = '&gt;';


  // ascii decimals to real symbols
  for (decimal in entities) {
    if (entities.hasOwnProperty(decimal)) {
      hash_map[String.fromCharCode(decimal)] = entities[decimal];
    }
  }

  return hash_map;
}
```

Comment: It is solved issue partially. I see characters like "&rsquo; &rdquo;" in output. How can I fix this?

Comment: add them to the entities table

Comment: Thank you. I find this site for all html entities http://htmlentities.net/html/entities/

Comment: If this solved your problem or helped, mark it as answered please!